# AS3 VideoEvent Listener - Event.Ready

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, flvplayer

I am trying to catch `READY` event of `FLV Video Player`. I am not quite sure what is going on with this codes. `FLV player` is imported by `Adobe Flash` and I need to start readyHandler whenever video is ready to play (Function will erase the "Video is loading" text). I used `video_oynattir` object flawlessly. However, these codes brake the animations...

```
video_oynattir.addEventListener(Event.READY, readyHandler);

function readyHandler(event:VideoEvent):void
{
    trace("hurray");
}
```

And produce this error:

> Accesss of possibly undefined property READY through a refferance with static type class*

If I comment out code segment. It executes perfectly.

Full code of stage as follows:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

var clickTAG:String = loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG;
var displayType:String = loaderInfo.parameters.displayType;

video_oynattir.autoPlay = false;

if(displayType == "collapse") {

    gotoAndStop("kapali");

}else{

    openButton.visible = false;
    gotoAndStop("acik");

}

video_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videodurdur);

function videodurdur(e:MouseEvent):void {

    if(video_oynattir.state == "playing") {

        video_oynattir.stop();

    }else{

        video_oynattir.play();

    }

}

video_oynattir.addEventListener(Event.READY, readyHandler);

function readyHandler(e:VideoEvent):void {

    trace("at");

}

//Accesss of possibly undefined property READY through a refferance with static type class

closeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeRichMedia);

function closeRichMedia(e:MouseEvent):void {

    video_oynattir.stop();
    ExternalInterface.call("dopushunlock");
    gotoAndPlay(3);
    openButton.visible = true;

}

openButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openRichMedia);

function openRichMedia(e:MouseEvent):void {

    ExternalInterface.call("dopushlock");
    gotoAndStop(2);
    openButton.visible = false;

}

clickButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoLink);

function gotoLink(e:MouseEvent):void {

    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(clickTAG), "_blank");

}

stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the event type the EventListener listens to to "**VideoEvent**":

```
video_oynattir.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, readyHandler);
```

Make sure to import "fl.video.VideoEvent".